# Database or file type for containing modular page contents?

Tags: database, database-design, web

I'm building a personal web and I have a problem planning my DB structure.

I have a portfolio page and each artwork has its own description page.

So I need to save contents in a file or a database.

The Description page has some guideline,

but the **length**, the **number**, and the **order** of elements are *free*.

for example a page may have just one paragraph or more,

and in each paragraph, many footage codes and text blocks can be mixed.

**the Question is:**

[image]

(I made a simple diagram to describe my needs).

What can I choose for my data type to save that contents structure maintaining the order?

I'm used to XML and I know XML can be one of the choice, but if the contents is big, it will be hard to read and slow.

I've heard that JSON alternates XML these days, but as I searched, JSON cannot maintain the order of elements, can it?

Waiting for clever recommendations:)
Thanks.

Comment: Does the database need to "see" inside the content? In other words, do you need to be able to query various content elements separately? If yes, what kinds of queries you expect you'll need? If no, then just store everything in BLOBs (in format of your choice, such as XML).

Comment: Thanks, I chose JSON type and importing it in a BLOB datatype in SQL as you advised.